# Laravel : Retrieve data of Services based on categories - Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am currently new to Laravel and Working on one project where

Services and Categories are in many to many relationships.
as

```
public function categories()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\category');
    }
```

and

```
public function services()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
    }
```

I have database tables as

```
Services [service_id, service_name]
Categories[category_id, category_name]
category_service[id, service_id, category_id]
```

I want to retrieve all services from DB table Service where category_id = 1.

Please suggest me which type of query will be helpful to write logic in the controller.

my controller code :

```
public function index()
    {
      $services = DB::table('services')->paginate(2);
      return view('user.home')->with('services', $services)->with('categories', Category::all())->with('$workingday', Workingday::all());

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Service::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    $query->where('categories.category_id', 1);
})->get();
```